# Pair of coordinate from list whose y axis is equal and x axis is bigger or smaller by 1 with one another

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, if-statement, indexing

So from the coordinates list, the found will be [(6,3),(5,3)]. I dont know how to fix my code.

```
Coordinates=[(6, 3),(4, 2),(5,3),(2,4)]
ix=0
Found =[]
    for c in coordinates:
        if ((c[0]+1,c[1]) in coordinates) and ((c[0]-1,c[1]) in coordinates):
            ix+=1
            Found.append(c)
            Found.append(c[ix+1])
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

You ask for “bigger OR smaller by 1”, so put this OR into your code instead of AND:

```
coordinates = [(6, 3), (4, 2), (5, 3), (2, 4)]
found = []
for c in coordinates:
    if ((c[0]+1, c[1]) in coordinates) or ((c[0]-1, c[1]) in coordinates):
        found.append(c)
```

`found` now contains `[(6, 3), (5, 3)]`

Comment: `or` lowercase @LIPU